# Why am I getting extra label text instead of the actual label that I put in?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Assume

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

If I do this from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)

```
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Line 2')
line_down, = plt.plot([3,2,1], label='Line 1')
plt.legend([line_up, line_down], ['Line Up', 'Line Down'])
```

I get `Line 2D(Line 1)` back if I pass it to `plt.legend()` instead of just the label itself e.g. `Line 1`. Why is that so?

It is a script that is about a year old and I can't remember that this came up a year ago!?

---

From my script:

```
relevant_line,  = plt.plot(x, relevant_normal_combination, label="Relevant phrases distr.")
# ...
plt.legend([relevant_line, nonrelevant_line,relevant_mu, nonrelevant_mu], loc = 1)
```

Gives me:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the issue - or maybe I just can't reproduce it. Could you put an image of the problem ?

Comment: @Mel I've added some relevant lines of my script and the resulting plot.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the example of the doc and your code, is the number of lists passed to `legend` (two in the doc, one in your code)

Let's take the example bellow:

```
line_no_legend = plt.plot([1,2],[1,1],c="k")
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Line 2',color="b")
line_down, = plt.plot([3,2,1], label='Line 1',color="g")

plt.legend([line_up, line_down], ['Line Up', 'Line Down'])  #left
plt.legend([line_up, line_down])                            #middle
plt.legend(handles=[line_up, line_down])                    #right
```

[image: legends behaviour]

The left is as the documentation, with two list: the handles and the new labels (strings)

The middle one is called with only one list, and has wrong colors and labels. That's because it expects a list of strings, not a list of handles (see [legend doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend))

The right one fixes the issue, by specifying `handles=`.

Comment: `plt.legend(handles=[relevant_line, nonrelevant_line,relevant_mu, nonrelevant_mu])` it is not working like this. This gives me `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'handles'`

Comment: Do you have this error when running my small example ?

Comment: Interestingly and against my expectations: *Yes*, unfortunately. I copy pasted your code adding `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` of course. ^^

Comment: That's weird.. I tested in python2 and 3, it worked for me. I have matplotlib 1.5.1

Comment: For me it is Python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.3.1 .. maybe that's the issue here. I try to update it and see if 1.5.1 works